# How to make objects viewable for current user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

What I'm trying to do is make an index page that only shows the current user's posts, interests and albums instead of all interests and albums on the site. To do this I've tried using the `current_user` method in the `PostsController` but I keep getting a no method error:

```
def index
  @posts = current_user.Post.all
  @albums = current_user.Album.all
  @interests = current_user.Interest.all
end
```

Comment: The case is important....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to use the plural and method names are downcase in Ruby:

```
def index 
  @posts = current_user.posts 
  @albums = current_user.albums 
  @interests = current_user.interests 
end
```

Furthermore you need to ensure that all these resources are actually associated with the user.

Comment: When I try that I get a NoMethodError that says: "undefined method `posts' for #<User:0x594b040>"

Comment: Do your database tables have `user_id` columns and are they set with the correct values? Does your `User` model have `has_many :posts` associations defined (same for `albums` and `interests`)?

Comment: I just added those and it worked. Thanks :)